# Cannot invoke function function with no arguments

Tags: swift

I am still new to iOS programming and trying to understand the logic behind the program. I am trying to call a function inside of the tableView function. I just want a piece of code inside of the tableView to run at a certain point. For a simple example

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    tableView.testFunction()
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    ...
    func testFunction() {
         println("test")
    }
    ...
}
```

But I get the error that I cannot invoke function with no arguments. I am new to swift so I apologize for the very basic question.

Answer (score 1):

One function *cannot* call a function that is inside another function.

You have defined `testFunction()` as a local function inside your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` function. No other function can see it; it is visible only inside `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` (and only to later code).

See [my book](http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch02.html#_function_in_function):

> A function declared in the body of a function (also called a local function) is available to be called by later code within the same scope, but is completely invisible outside its scope.

Comment: Then how would I configure the tableView from outside of the tableView function? Not necessarily in the viewDidLoad but pressing a button, for example.

Comment: I don't know what "configure the tableView from outside of the tableView function" means and I have no earthly notion of what you are trying to do. If you want the runtime to call `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` for you, then tell the table view to `reloadData()`.